# Power BI Desktop - Relative Date Slicer Defaulting to Days

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Hoping this is a simple one to resolve.

I have a dataset, a SQL View, with the data imported into my PBIX. I have a date slicer and a number of tables, matrices and charts, over 2 pages. All update whenever I change my slicer, great.

One of my charts needs to show the last 12 months only. I choose Relative Date Filtering from the Visual level filters, select "is in the last", 12 and months from the various drop-downs. When I click Apply filter, my chart goes blank, even though there is data. When I click off the chart and back on again, the drop-down has changed to Days, not months. I have tried with various different options and always defaults back to days.

My Date field is definitely a Date. I have also tried adding a Date table and using that date too but the same thing happens.

[image: Relative Date Filtering]

Is it me or is there a bug?

Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Thats what I thought